# Water Damage sides of the shower

Tags: waterproofing, water-damage

Anybody know if this is just a patch job or should I get a professional to look for further damage?

[image]
[image]

I peeled off the existing primer/ paint then this is what I got. Can I just remove the mold and recaulk and reprime/repaint these two areas?

Comment: I agree with Gil in that this is a lot more than just a caulking and repainting exercise.  First thing you need to find out, and fix, is how the water is getting to the wall and behind the drywall (irrespective of what type of drywall it is).  Can you provide a picture or two of that same area from inside the shower?  It may be that the shower enclosure is not installed properly.

Comment: Also, is there tile on the inside of the shower?

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious problem you need professional help. It appears the drywall is the wrong type and will need to be replaced. You can "just remove the mold and recaulk and reprime/repaint these two areas?" about every year with it getting worse each time. When you have mold in the walls you do not mess around. Are you sure the moisture is not coming from some place else? What is on the other side of the wall. You will learn a lot when the drywall is removed.